# Android, Reusing Not Layouts, But Views via XML

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a button I use a lot in one of my layouts. Or rather, I have like ten buttons all with the same text color, background color, text size, width, and height. I don't want to define all of these parameters for each button. So I want to be able to write something like...

```
<include view="@layout/standard_button"
    android:id="@+id/button-id"
    android:text="button-specific-text"/>
```

But of course, there is no include `view=""`, there is only include layout, and include layout the `xml` file as a Layout, not a View, so setting the text is not possible and when I `findViewById()` in my activity, it would refer to a Layout and not a View.

Is there something like `<include view="...` ?

Comment: What you can do is simply make style for your button in themes.xml and just add your button with the style parameter and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a layout with your customized style button that you want to use multiple times, and wrap it in a `<merge>` tag like below sample.

And then you can reuse it over and over again using the `include` tag in any other layout.

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</merge>
```

Usage within any other layout, assuming the top layout named as `my_button.xml`

```
<include layout="@layout/my_button" />
```

Comment: Can attributes such as the `text` attribute be overridden with this method?

Comment: @Cheticamp yes it can be done programmatically